# You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

Tags: steam

I have recently moved over from SteamOS which is Debian Wheazy. None of the other fixes have not worked, I tried getting steam both through Steam itself and the Ubuntu Center.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using and what "other fixes" have you tried that did not work and please post the output that lists the missing 32-bit libraries so I can look them up for you.

Comment: For a fresh install of 14.04.2  -  you're using the HWE mesa stack & need to install the ..lts-utopic package(s). So `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386` should prove useful

Comment: the current hwe stack is for vivid now that utopic is eol.

Answer (score 49):

Assuming libc.so.6 is the only one you are missing, open a terminal and execute the following commands to install the missing library (be careful here and do not accept changes unless you are happy with the changes ie may uninstall stuff you want to keep!!):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Please post any errors.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether this would have worked for the OP, but I got the same error from Steam on Debian 8, and installing `libc6-i386` worked for me.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package libc6-i386`

Comment: @Zenon What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @mchid Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Comment: @Zenon Some people use mate on older computers. Are you using the i386 version or the X86_64 version of mate ?

Comment: @mchid The ARM64. Raspberry Pi 3B. If it just doesn’t work on that architecture I wish they’d make it more obvious. I get that the RPi is far from a gaming desktop but Steam has some older games that require very little in the way of specs.

Comment: @Zenon My friend told me that steam games are usually available online and that you don't usually need to install steam to play the games (I am not sure myself). Also, how did you install steam? Did you use `apt-get`? The command would be: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install steam` or `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install steamcmd`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install steam` did not work on my Ubuntu 18, but `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386` helped.

Answer (score 8):

As of time of this post, using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I first tried installing using `steam_latest.deb` from their website, but got the OP error.

To resolve I ran this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

And it would work after.

Comment: Not working on my Ubuntu 18.

Comment: @Sklavit Does apt-get find the package at all on Ubuntu 18? In my case Steam was able to function but finally the game I was trying to play only worked on Steam for PC T_T. Can you try sudo apt-get install steamcmd as well? (untested, but I saw it on someone else's response)

Comment: Linux Mint 19.3 here. This actually worked. Thanks! Apparently, `dpkg` did not attempt to install the dependencies. Running `sudo apt-get install steam` right after fixed the issue for me.

Comment: the same problem. 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: I found it necessary to `apt-get install steam` and also `apt-get install steamcmd`

Answer (score 4):

If like me, mchid answer didn't solved your issue, try making a symlink to libc.so.6 and reinstalling steam from [steamcmd](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD):

```
find /lib -name libc.so.6
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
mkdir ~/steamcmd2 && cd $_
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
./steamcmd.sh
```

Then

```
./steam.sh
```

Comment: There is no need to use `find` and `grep`. `find` alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

##### Install Steam

To install all the missing packages automatically without any 404 errors or missing `libc.so.6` or bad ELF.

Enter `Software & Updates` and uncheck all **except** the first one: `Canonical-supported free and open-source software (main)` and close the window.

That's all. Now, after steam is installed and running, you can go `Software & Updates` and check to the original state.