# You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run

Tags: 14.04, steam

I'm getting an error message:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and steam may not run:
```

These are all the libraries it says I am missing.

```
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0
libpango-1.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
libcairo.so.2
libpango-1.0.so.0
libnss3.so
libnssutil3.so
libsmime3.so
libplc4.so
libnspr4.so
libXss.so.1
```

I honestly have no idea what I am supposed to do or even where to start. Some guidance would be much appreciated. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that means anything. I am just trying to get my access to Steam back.

Comment: Can you give me the out put of when you try to start 'steam' in terminal.

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602637/you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libc-so-6)