# Error while installing Steam on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

I am trying to install Steam on my Ubuntu and am getting this error:

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for prince: 
.......................................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.48) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libelf1:i386 (>= 0.142) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libexpat1:i386 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libgcc1:i386 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libllvm3.4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                    libtxc-dxtn0:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libx11-6:i386 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-glx0:i386 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-present0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb-sync1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxcb1:i386 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxdamage1:i386 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxfixes3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libxxf86vm1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libudev1:i386 but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libudev0:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Press return to continue:
```

If I press `enter`, I get a window saying:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libc.so.6
```

Looking at responses to [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602637/you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libc-so-6), which mentions a similar issue, I tried to do an update and install but got this error:

```
prince@Devil-Device:~$ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
[sudo] password for prince: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
prince@Devil-Device:~$
```

Please Help.

Comment: I think it's because of 32 and 64 Bit libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You have broken packages run

```
sudo apt-get -f install 

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then try to again.

If you are having the same issues you may need to add packages  (32 bit) if running 64.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Wine 1.4 if all else fails: This supports win32 and win64.
First remove all other wine pakages

```
sudo apt-get purge wine1.7
```

Then install wine 1.4

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.4 && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Set your wine prefix for your system this is for 32bit.

```
export WINEPREFIX=prefix32



export WINEARCH=win32
```

Run:

```
winecfg
```

Comment: Did not work, Still the same issue

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue myself for quite some time. When I tried to install the packages, half of them wouldn't install. What personally worked for me, was deleting that install of Steam (via `sudo apt-get remove steam` or `sudo apt-get purge steam`) and doing a fresh install via `sudo apt-get install steam -y`. Now I can't say that that install will work 100% (it didn't for me at first, I had to reinstall my graphics card drivers), but hopefully that helps. :)