# Steam saying I am missing "libc.so.6", even though it is in my libraries folder

Tags: package-management, dpkg, steam, libraries

I a question like this has been asked before, but none of the solutions I found have worked, and I think my problem is different, because it's more like Steam not detecting the library. Exact error message:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6

When I try run `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386`, it returns this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu3).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-5-multilib : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libc6-dev-x32 : Depends: libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried `apt-get -f install`, which returns this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.23-0ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**It looks like my problem is that the file is there, but for some reason it is not detected by Steam.**

Comment: sorry but this answer does work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/602637/you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libc-so-6 It is the missing package you need. Otherwise you really need to add to the question what you tried and why those things did not work.

Comment: I have edited my question heavily, and would like you to unmark it as a duplicate, as I believe that my question is different.

Comment: What's the output of `uname -m` and `apt-cache policy libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-amd64:i386`? I'm curious what installed `libc6-dev-amd64:i386` if you're on AMD64 architecture and you should probably remove it (native-architecture glibc development files are in `libc6-dev`).

Comment: uname -m: x86_64, apt-cache policy libc6-dev-i386 libc6-dev-amd64:i386: libc6-dev-i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libc6-dev-amd64:i386:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status