# My friend cant download steam on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

My friend keeps getting the error that says ERROR- You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:libc.so.6

He is running xubuntu on a 32 bit chromeOS

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install steam?  Paraphrased and incomplete pieces of errors are not very helpful in understanding the problem. You should include all of the steps it takes to reproduce error(s) as well as the entire error copied/pasted verbatim.

Comment: Have a look at : [You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602637/you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libc-so-6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602637/you-are-missing-the-following-32-bit-libraries-and-steam-may-not-run-libc-so-6)